# Bind Data in Repeater Control & use a Hyperlink to link a database record

Tags: bind, repeater

I need a help regarding Repeater Control & Data Binding.

I created a Page that displays articles (Containing Title & Post) from the database using Repeater Control.

The table structure is:

> ID
>   Title
>   Post

The aspx code is:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Eval("title") %>
<asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("post") %>' Font-Bold="true"/>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
</article>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The C# Code is:

```
    string qw = "Select title, post from articles";
    RepDetails.DataSource = dbc.ConnectDataBaseReturnDS(qw);
    RepDetails.DataBind();
```

Using this Code i can display the articles in the page, but what i want is that when someone clicks on the title of a post, a new page opens with that particular post. (same functionality that we see in normal websites/blogs.)

I really can't figure out how to do this.  i was thinking about using Query String or something, but not having any idea.

Please help me, i am new to ASP.Net and forgive me if i made any mistake as it's first time i am posting a thread here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Change your ItemTemplate to use an ASP.NET HyperLink, like so:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <HyperLinkid="hlnkTitle" Text='<%#Eval("title") %>' NavigateUrl="Details.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("ID") %>" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("post") %>' Font-Bold="true"/>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Note:** I am assuming that the page that displays the post is called `Details.aspx`. Also, instead of opening a new window, I suggest taking the user to the details page because this is how it is usually done. If you really want to open a new window, let me know and I'll post that code.

Now, on `Details.aspx` you would capture the ID of the post to display like so:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    if(!this.IsPostBack) {
        int idPost = Int32.Parse(this.Request.QueryString["ID"];
        //PERFORM YOUR SQL USING THE ID HERE
        //THEN YOU CAN BIND THE VALUES TO ANY SERVER CONTROLS YOU WANT
    }
}
```

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: thank you so much sir, i will try the code given by you, even i don;t want to open in a new window, by that i only means new page. :)

Comment: i will try the code and post here.

a typo u made ;)   QueryString("ID")  i found it to be ["ID"]   


the code worked, thank you for the logic

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I edited my answer regarding the querystring access. Also, if this answer helped, please click the up arrow to show that it was useful. If this answer solved your question, please click the checkbox to mark it as the accepted answer. It's how we "show our love" in StackOverflow! :)